# Is it possible to start a D3JS pie chart with all values being 0?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm making a simple tool to display a set of values that are manipulated by the user. I want all the values to start at 0 and when the data is manipulated, to grow from there.

I have everything setup except that I get errors in the console when I start all my values at 0.

Is this possible?

Here's the code I have at the moment (which is working if the values are greater than 0):

```
    var width = this.get('width');
    var height = this.get('height');
    var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
    var color = this.get('chartColors');
    var data = this.get('chartData');

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius)
        .innerRadius(0);


    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) { return d.count; });


    var id = this.$().attr('id');
    var svg = d3.select("#"+id)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var g = svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(pie(data));

    g.enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .each(function(d){ this._current = d; })
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color[i]; })
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", 2);
```

Comment: The problem is a conceptual one -- if everything is 0, how are you going to draw a pie chart? You could however start with an empty data set and add new data as it becomes greater than zero.

Comment: Ok. That helps a lot. I've added in some logic to determine if the data set passed in has values that total greater than 1, if so, then I'm passing in the array of values, otherwise I'm passing in an empty array. Next question though: When initially drawing the pie, how do I animate in the pie with the first value. it works when I update it but not when I draw it initially.

Comment: It sounds like you would need to start the transition with the width of the pie wedge being 0. You would do it in the same way as for the update transition, except that you start from 0 instead of the previous value.

Comment: I don't know how to implement that advice. is there any chance you could whip up a code example?

Comment: Ok, turns out it's a bit more complicated -- random example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MX7JC/665/) (lines 49-53).

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: Haven't validated it yet.

Comment: Yes. the random example did solve it. Wanna put in an official answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: Sure, thanks. I'll add a little bit of explanation as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a conceptual one -- if everything is 0, how are you going to draw a pie chart? You could however start with an empty data set and add new data as it becomes greater than zero. That leaves the problem of animating the growth of a pie chart segment from 0 to its desired size.

For this, you can animate the end angle of the pie chart segments starting at the start angle. The easiest way to do this is to copy the corresponding data object and tween the angle:

```
.each(function(d) {
    this._current = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(d));
    this._current.endAngle = this._current.startAngle;
})
.transition().duration(dur).attrTween("d", arcTween);
```

Random example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MX7JC/665/).

Comment: In my case I didn't need the JSON parse/stringify pieces, just assigning "d" to "_current.

Comment: Be aware that this will modify the original object, i.e. if you want to set the angles later using that object, you will get incorrect values.